# Solving a system of nonlinear equations with 8 variables

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve this 10 nonlinear equations in 8 variables, expressing the variable as a function of one another. I have tried using Solve and Reduce, but couldn't get any result.

```
-a0 bo^2 e1 + a0^2 bo g1 + a0^3 g2 == 0

 a0 b1 bo - a1 bo^2 - 2 a0 b1 bo e1 - a1 bo^2 e1 + a0^2 b1 g1 + 
  2 a0 a1 bo g1 + 3 a0^2 a1 g2 == 0

-a0 b1^2 - 3 a0 b1 bo + a1 b1 bo + 4 a0 b2 bo + 3 a1 bo^2 - 
  4 a2 bo^2 - a0 b1^2 e1 - 2 a1 b1 bo e1 - 2 a0 b2 bo e1 - 
  a2 bo^2 e1 + 2 a0 a1 b1 g1 + a0^2 b2 g1 + a1^2 bo g1 + 
  2 a0 a2 bo g1 + 3 a0 a1^2 g2 + 3 a0^2 a2 g2 == 0

a0 b1^2 - 3 a0 b1 b2 + 2 a0 b1 bo - a1 b1 bo - 3 a2 b1 bo - 
  10 a0 b2 bo + 6 a1 b2 bo - 2 a1 bo^2 + 10 a2 bo^2 - 9 a3 bo^2 - 
  a1 b1^2 e1 - 2 a0 b1 b2 e1 - 2 a2 b1 bo e1 - 2 a1 b2 bo e1 - 
  a3 bo^2 e1 + a1^2 b1 g1 + 2 a0 a2 b1 g1 + 2 a0 a1 b2 g1 + 
  2 a1 a2 bo g1 + 2 a0 a3 bo g1 + a1^3 g2 + 6 a0 a1 a2 g2 + 
  3 a0^2 a3 g2 == 0

-a2 b1^2 + 3 a0 b1 b2 + a1 b1 b2 - 4 a0 b2^2 + 9 a2 b1 bo - 
  11 a3 b1 bo + 6 a0 b2 bo - 12 a1 b2 bo + 4 a2 b2 bo - 6 a2 bo^2 + 
  21 a3 bo^2 - a2 b1^2 e1 - 2 a1 b1 b2 e1 - a0 b2^2 e1 - 
  2 a3 b1 bo e1 - 2 a2 b2 bo e1 + 2 a1 a2 b1 g1 + 2 a0 a3 b1 g1 + 
  a1^2 b2 g1 + 2 a0 a2 b2 g1 + a2^2 bo g1 + 2 a1 a3 bo g1 + 
  3 a1^2 a2 g2 + 3 a0 a2^2 g2 + 6 a0 a1 a3 g2 == 0

3 a2 b1^2 - 4 a3 b1^2 - 3 a1 b1 b2 + a2 b1 b2 + 6 a0 b2^2 - a1 b2^2 - 
  6 a2 b1 bo + 27 a3 b1 bo + 6 a1 b2 bo - 6 a2 b2 bo - 2 a3 b2 bo - 
  12 a3 bo^2 - a3 b1^2 e1 - 2 a2 b1 b2 e1 - a1 b2^2 e1 - 
  2 a3 b2 bo e1 + a2^2 b1 g1 + 2 a1 a3 b1 g1 + 2 a1 a2 b2 g1 + 
  2 a0 a3 b2 g1 + 2 a2 a3 bo g1 + 3 a1 a2^2 g2 + 3 a1^2 a3 g2 + 
  6 a0 a2 a3 g2 == 0

-2 a2 b1^2 + 10 a3 b1^2 + 2 a1 b1 b2 - a2 b1 b2 - 3 a3 b1 b2 - 
  2 a0 b2^2 + a1 b2^2 - 16 a3 b1 bo + 2 a2 b2 bo + 8 a3 b2 bo - 
  2 a3 b1 b2 e1 - a2 b2^2 e1 + 2 a2 a3 b1 g1 + a2^2 b2 g1 + 
  2 a1 a3 b2 g1 + a3^2 bo g1 + a2^3 g2 + 6 a1 a2 a3 g2 + 
  3 a0 a3^2 g2 == 0

-6 a3 b1^2 + 9 a3 b1 b2 - a3 b2^2 - 6 a3 b2 bo - a3 b2^2 e1 + 
  a3^2 b1 g1 + 2 a2 a3 b2 g1 + 3 a2^2 a3 g2 + 3 a1 a3^2 g2 == 0

-6 a3 b1 b2 + 3 a3 b2^2 + a3^2 b2 g1 + 3 a2 a3^2 g2 == 0

-2 a3 b2^2 + a3^3 g2 == 0,

Variables{a0, a1, a2, a3, bo, b1, b2, e1}
```

I want to express the variables as a function of one another, like, for example

```
a0 -> 0, 

 a1 -> (-b1 g1 - b1 Sqrt[g1^2 + 4 g2 \[Alpha]^2 + 4 g2 \[Beta]])/(
  2 g2),

 a2 -> 0,

 bo -> 0
```

Comment: 1. Where did these equations come from? 2. Do you have assumptions on these variables that you forgot to tell *Mathematica* (e.g. variables being real or positive)?

Comment: I used the generalized Kudryashov methods to evaluate a nonlinear Schrodinger equation. To the best of my knowledge, variables are real.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Clear[eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10 , a0, a1, a2, 
  a3, bo, b1, b2, e1];
eq1 = -a0 bo^2 e1 + a0^2 bo g1 + a0^3 g2 == 0;
eq2 = a0 b1 bo - a1 bo^2 - 2 a0 b1 bo e1 - a1 bo^2 e1 + a0^2 b1 g1 + 
    2 a0 a1 bo g1 + 3 a0^2 a1 g2 == 0;
eq3 = -a0 b1^2 - 3 a0 b1 bo + a1 b1 bo + 4 a0 b2 bo + 3 a1 bo^2 - 
    4 a2 bo^2 - a0 b1^2 e1 - 2 a1 b1 bo e1 - 2 a0 b2 bo e1 - 
    a2 bo^2 e1 + 2 a0 a1 b1 g1 + a0^2 b2 g1 + a1^2 bo g1 + 
    2 a0 a2 bo g1 + 3 a0 a1^2 g2 + 3 a0^2 a2 g2 == 0;
eq4 = a0 b1^2 - 3 a0 b1 b2 + 2 a0 b1 bo - a1 b1 bo - 3 a2 b1 bo - 
    10 a0 b2 bo + 6 a1 b2 bo - 2 a1 bo^2 + 10 a2 bo^2 - 9 a3 bo^2 - 
    a1 b1^2 e1 - 2 a0 b1 b2 e1 - 2 a2 b1 bo e1 - 2 a1 b2 bo e1 - 
    a3 bo^2 e1 + a1^2 b1 g1 + 2 a0 a2 b1 g1 + 2 a0 a1 b2 g1 + 
    2 a1 a2 bo g1 + 2 a0 a3 bo g1 + a1^3 g2 + 6 a0 a1 a2 g2 + 
    3 a0^2 a3 g2 == 0;
eq5 = -a2 b1^2 + 3 a0 b1 b2 + a1 b1 b2 - 4 a0 b2^2 + 9 a2 b1 bo - 
    11 a3 b1 bo + 6 a0 b2 bo - 12 a1 b2 bo + 4 a2 b2 bo - 6 a2 bo^2 + 
    21 a3 bo^2 - a2 b1^2 e1 - 2 a1 b1 b2 e1 - a0 b2^2 e1 - 
    2 a3 b1 bo e1 - 2 a2 b2 bo e1 + 2 a1 a2 b1 g1 + 2 a0 a3 b1 g1 + 
    a1^2 b2 g1 + 2 a0 a2 b2 g1 + a2^2 bo g1 + 2 a1 a3 bo g1 + 
    3 a1^2 a2 g2 + 3 a0 a2^2 g2 + 6 a0 a1 a3 g2 == 0;
eq6 = 3 a2 b1^2 - 4 a3 b1^2 - 3 a1 b1 b2 + a2 b1 b2 + 6 a0 b2^2 - 
    a1 b2^2 - 6 a2 b1 bo + 27 a3 b1 bo + 6 a1 b2 bo - 6 a2 b2 bo - 
    2 a3 b2 bo - 12 a3 bo^2 - a3 b1^2 e1 - 2 a2 b1 b2 e1 - 
    a1 b2^2 e1 - 2 a3 b2 bo e1 + a2^2 b1 g1 + 2 a1 a3 b1 g1 + 
    2 a1 a2 b2 g1 + 2 a0 a3 b2 g1 + 2 a2 a3 bo g1 + 3 a1 a2^2 g2 + 
    3 a1^2 a3 g2 + 6 a0 a2 a3 g2 == 0;
eq7 = -2 a2 b1^2 + 10 a3 b1^2 + 2 a1 b1 b2 - a2 b1 b2 - 3 a3 b1 b2 - 
    2 a0 b2^2 + a1 b2^2 - 16 a3 b1 bo + 2 a2 b2 bo + 8 a3 b2 bo - 
    2 a3 b1 b2 e1 - a2 b2^2 e1 + 2 a2 a3 b1 g1 + a2^2 b2 g1 + 
    2 a1 a3 b2 g1 + a3^2 bo g1 + a2^3 g2 + 6 a1 a2 a3 g2 + 
    3 a0 a3^2 g2 == 0;
eq8 = -6 a3 b1^2 + 9 a3 b1 b2 - a3 b2^2 - 6 a3 b2 bo - a3 b2^2 e1 + 
    a3^2 b1 g1 + 2 a2 a3 b2 g1 + 3 a2^2 a3 g2 + 3 a1 a3^2 g2 == 0;
eq9 = -6 a3 b1 b2 + 3 a3 b2^2 + a3^2 b2 g1 + 3 a2 a3^2 g2 == 0;
eq10 = -2 a3 b2^2 + a3^3 g2 == 0;
vars = {a0, a1, a2, a3, bo, b1, b2, e1};

NSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10 }, vars]
```

Since my computer is slow, it takes sometime to give results. Please note that you have 10 equations and 8 variables, implying that the system is over-identified. You should first deal with the identification problem, if possible reduce the system to 8 equations and 8 variables for the solution.